# Not able to configure cluster settings instance type using mlflow api 2.0 to enable model serving

Tags: python, databricks, aws-databricks

I'm able to enable model serving by using the mlflow api 2.0 with the following code...

```
    instance = f'https://{workspace}.cloud.databricks.com'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_workflow_access_token}'} 
     
    # Enable Model Serving 
    import requests
    url = f'{instance}/api/2.0/mlflow/endpoints/enable'
    requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={"registered_model_name": f'{model_name}'})
```

However this automatically sets the cluster setting instance type to be m5a.xlarge, which I DO NOT want it to be. I can manually go into the settings on the UI (image below) and change it to be m4.large but I want to be able to do this within the api code above so that I don't have to manually go into the settings and change it. This would allow me to enable and disable serving models without ever needing to interact with the UI.

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing any documentation for that endpoint besides a [question](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001UC6aZCAT/how-to-enable-and-disable-model-serving-using-rest-api) on the Databricks Community. Maybe you can try to set `"node_type_id": "m4.large"` in the json request?

Comment: I tried that already to no avail. Thanks!